# In keyboard > Shortcuts; How can I set the Left Alt button to no longer grab windows on mouse click?

Tags: shortcut-keys

In keyboard > Shortcuts; How can I set the Left Alt button to no longer grab windows on mouse click?

I'd like to set it to Super instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this behaviour by setting the **mouse-button-modifier** property in the dconf database, open a terminal and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "<Super>"
```

To restore the initial settings, use this command instead:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier
```